# Update columns based on record count and count total

Tags: sql, count, max

I need some help writing a script to update a table.

The table has the following:

```
| StudentID | Name | Record | Label | 
|         1 | Ed   |      1 |     1 |
|         1 | Ed   |      1 |     1 |
|         1 | Ed   |      1 |     1 |
|         1 | Ed   |      1 |     1 |
|         2 | Bob  |      1 |     1 |
|         2 | Bob  |      1 |     1 |
|         2 | Bob  |      1 |     1 |
|         2 | Bob  |      1 |     1 |
```

I would like to update the Record and Label columns, so that the query would increment the Record column from 1 to n for the same StudentId. The Label column would also need to be updated to display the record # of total number of records for that StudentId.

The result for Ed should be:

```
| StudentID | Name | Record |  Label  |
|         1 | Ed   |      1 | 1 of 4  |
|         1 | Ed   |      2 | 2 of 4  |
|         1 | Ed   |      3 | 3 of 4  |
|         1 | Ed   |      4 | 4 of 4  |
```

Hoping someone can help me with this.

Comment: You should specify which platform you're using. And is it possible that you're going about your problem in entirely the wrong way? Are you just trying to make copies of a students from another table?

Comment: This isn't something that should be stored in the database. These are calculated values, which should be calculated when you need them to prevent them from becoming stale data in the database.

Comment: I am using SQL Server to try to write a procedure to update this table.  I am using test data for the problem.    Lets just say that a StudentId is unique and no new records would be added to the table to further increase the record number.  Therefore, the record number is a static field and so is label once the update is applied to the records in the table.